# Voip call Developing in android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, sip

I would like to make an application similar to SipDroid on android. I took a look at SipDemo from developer.android.com and at the android.net.sip package. My question is, when you make/receive a call, how can you get the audio stream to encrypt/decrypt it before is being sent/played back to the user? Is there a tutorial about this somewhere? I am aware that I need a sip account and real devices with android 2.3. I would like to get the AudioStream before it's sent (for encryption) and to receive the AudioStream before it gets played-back to the user(for decryption).

Guys please help me .
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Android 2.3 API it is not possilbe to "get" to the autio stream to en/decrypt it, because the [android.net.rtp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) package is not open to the "normal" developers. This only opened from android 3.1 onwards.

In order to get an encryption running in lower android API versions have a look at the [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) project. It is open source and fully implements what you're asking for. However, it is kind of complicated to get into it since the app isn't very simple. But give it a try.

Comment: Actually i saw that CSIPSIMPLE thing but its more complicated n tough to build in my eclipse n run or on device so i just want to know how to encrypt or decrypt audio stream for any version i ready to implement code but need guidance for encryption of voice or audio so do u u knw something abt this ?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it won't be possible for you to encrypt the audio stream before version 3.1. I had a similar project this year and I decided to go with the libraries used in CSipSimple. The problem is that you cannot access the android.net.rtp package where the audio stream is located. [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) is used to transfer the audio over the network. In order to encrypt it in version 3.1 onwards you'd have to extend the audio stream class and override certain methods yourself. Have a look at SRTP.

Comment: O thanks lot , i want to know how u encrypted in 3.1 or more means just idea how u got signals in ur code n encrypted that data n sent ? hope u dnt mind .. :)

Comment: Well, I didn't do it this way, I used the libraries from the CSipSimple project because I wanted it to run on phones too (Android 4.0 was not out yet and Android 3.x is only for tablets).
If you want to encrypt it yourself you will have to look at the code. I don't think it will be very easy. And it is also possible that the actual audio handling is in the native (c++) code so that it can't be handled in Java itself.
If I were you, I'd have another look at CSipSimple. It is complicated at the beginning but with the time you'll find your way. And it is possible to make a MUCH simpler client.

Comment: And the best thing, it will run even on Android 1.5 phones where as the other one only runs on tablets and the very few newer phones that support android 4.0.

Comment: I installed all the libraries n dependencies in my pc of CSIPSIMPLE now i want to know how to start our project n coding its too complex please help me out :)

Comment: @David : I'm also stuck with CSipSimple. Could you forward that mail for me too please?